# Java ReentrantReadWriteLock requests

Tags: java, thread-safety, reentrantreadwritelock, readwritelock

Just a quick question about ReadWriteLocks in Java (specifically the ReentrantReadWriteLock implementation) as I don’t find the sun documentation clear.

What happens if a read lock is held by a thread when a write lock is requested by another? 
Does the write lock thread have to wait for all currently held read-locks to be released?
Also, do all new read-lock requests get blocked until the write-lock is granted and released?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc explains this:

> This class does not impose a reader
>   or writer preference   ordering for
>   lock access.  However, it does support
>   an optional   *fairness*
>   policy.  When constructed as fair,
>   threads   contend for entry using an
>   approximately arrival-order policy.
>   When   the write lock is released
>   either the longest-waiting single
>   writer   will be assigned the write
>   lock, or if there is a reader waiting 
>   longer than any writer, the set of
>   readers will be assigned the   read
>   lock.  When constructed as non-fair,
>   the order of entry to the   lock need
>   not be in arrival order.  In either
>   case, if readers are   active and a
>   writer enters the lock then no
>   subsequent readers will   be granted
>   the read lock until after that writer
>   has acquired and   released the write
>   lock.

---

> What happens if a read lock is held by a thread when a write lock is requested by another? Does the write lock thread have to wait for all currently held read-locks to be released?

Yes, the writer will have to wait. But it will only wait for the currently held read locks. Any readers arriving later will queue after the writer.

> Also, do all new read-lock requests get blocked until the write-lock is granted and released?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

A `ReadWriteLock` cannot have a write lock held at the same time as read locks. Requests for, say, a write lock when a read lock is held will result in blocking or a fail.